# how to access sharepoint folder using graph api

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell

In my SharePoint site Document Library, I have a folder called OneDriveInventory and I have a few file inside.

I'm trying to access those file but it look like my Uri request is wrong so I would be really appreciated I can get any help or suggestion on how to fix this.

```
 Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteId/drives/$driveId/OneDriveInventory/$($filename)" -Method GET -OutFile $filePath -Headers $headers
```

Comment: Try this ... `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteId/drive/root://OneDriveInventory` ... it may work for you, not sure but that concept worked for me.  Mind you, I had a filename at the end so not 100% sure if it will list the files in the directory.  I guess you'll find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one SharePoint document library in which I created **folder** named **`OneDriveInventory`** and added **files** like below:

[image]

You can make use of below **Graph API call** to access file in the above folder:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteID>/drives/<driveID>/root:/OneDriveInventory:/children/<filename>
```

When I ran the above query in **[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)**, I got **results** successfully like below:

[image]

To get the **same results** from PowerShell, I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** using below PowerShell script:

```
$tenantId = <tenantID>
$applicationId = <appID>
$secret= <secret>
$param = @{
        Uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        Method = 'Post';
        Body = @{ 
            grant_type = 'client_credentials'; 
            scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'; 
            client_id = $applicationId; 
            client_secret = $secret
        }
   }
$result = Invoke-RestMethod @param
$token = $result.access_token
```

**Response:**

[image]

To access **file** from folder, I used below PowerShell script:

```
$siteID = "3b23b598-f5e4-461f-b038-xxxxxx"
$driveID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$filename = "sridevi.txt"

$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
$response=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteID/drives/$driveID/root:/OneDriveInventory:/children/$($filename)" -Method GET -OutFile $filePath -Headers $headers
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran **`$response.Content`**, I got **full response** like below:

[image]